# How to convert varchar to decimal(38,2)?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have a problem converting from a varchar '000000113754' to decimal 1137.54

I'm comparing two expressions:

```
1. select STUFF('000000113754', LEN('000000113754') - 1, 0, '.')

2. select STUFF([dbo].fn_PrepareNumeric(('000000113754' + '-'), '+','-'), LEN('000000113754') - 1, 0, '.')
```

The function `fn_PrepareNumeric` just checks for the sign and appends '-' in front if the sign is `-`. That's all.

The problem is that the first expression gives me the correct varchar - `0000001137.54`, and the second one does not: `-000000113.754`

Cannot figure out why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert varchar to decimal(38,2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085924/how-to-convert-varchar-to-decimal38-2)

Comment: This is actually my question :)

Comment: Neither can we since you did not post the code of your function. But why do this at all? Why so COMPLICATED? Just convert directly to int, then divide by 100.0 (to avoid integer division) and cast to your desired datatype.

Comment: And since you posted the question twice - just delete the other.

Comment: I did not know I posted twice